# NSError.setUserInfoValueProvider infinite loop

Tags: swift, foundation, nserror

[`NSError.setUserInfoValueProvider(forDomain:provider:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nserror/1408064-setuserinfovalueprovider) was introduced in MacOS 10.11/iOS 9 as a way to populate the `userInfo` dictionary of an `NSError` for the given error domain using a block, thereby avoiding a lot of boilerplate and repetition in code that may throw.

I tried to use it like this:

```
if NSError.userInfoValueProvider(forDomain: "Test") == nil {
    NSError.setUserInfoValueProvider(forDomain: "Test"){ err, userInfoKey in
        print("This is an error:", err, userInfoKey)
        return nil
    }
}
```

The call site looks like this:

```
throw NSError(domain: "Test", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
```

When the error is thrown, the log is filled with "This is an error:", but the error itself or the `userInfoKey` is never printed out. The program finally aborts with a final message in the log:

> warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data
>   in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information
>   available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that printing `err` in

```
print("This is an error:", err, userInfoKey)
```

calls the same value provider recursively, because the string representation of the error is determined. The program then eventually crashes with a stack overflow. You can verify that by setting a breakpoint on that line.

If you change the line to

```
print("This is an error:", userInfoKey)
```

then everything works as expected.

Comment: Indeed that is the problem — NSError will do its best to render a good string representation, going through all of its `userInfo` in the process. When this happens in the block that is supposed to supply the same `userInfo` values, that leads to infinite recursion.